# Weird problem with ntheorem resulting from some particular combination of packages

Tags: errors, ntheorem, undefined

The following problem arose in a larger document, which I stripped down to the following MWE. Let me stress that it really is a MWE – changing any line makes it work. Unfortunately I want to use all these packages in this way.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{thm}\label{label}
  Text
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get an Undefined control sequence error in the line opening the theorem saying

```
\scshape  ...pe \relax \def \tempu {u}\def \tempo 
                                                  {ol}\ifx \f@shape \tempu \...l.16 \begin{thm}\label{label}
```

which doesn't look familiar at all (these lines are not contained in the aux file or anywhere else I could find).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try adding `spanish.lcroman` to the babel options. Some language make certain chars active, something other packages does not expect.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, you may suffer with version issue, please update your setup then try...

Comment: @MadyYuvi which latex version are you using? My TL2019 was updated yesterday and it gave Michaels error.

Comment: My version is `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210)` and I am using `LaTeX->dvips->PS2PDF`, generally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue depends on interaction between `cfr-lm` and `babel-spanish`, when the Roman numerals are realized with small caps. The `ntheorem` package isn't involved, so I removed it from the example code below.

You can work around the issue by providing protected default values for `\tempo` and `\tempu`.

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}

\protected\def\tempu{}
\protected\def\tempo{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{thm}\label{label}
  Text
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```